# linux shell script using djvused program not working

Tags: linux, bash, shell, djvu

I want to write a script that renames the pages of a DJVU file recursively.
From http://djvu.sourceforge.net/doc/man/djvused.html I know that the command to do that on a single page (say call page 5 of the bundle with name 6) is

```
djvused file.djvu -e 'select 5; set-page-title 6; save'
```

But then I have troubles when trying to do it recursively, namely running the script

```
./for.sh
```

which is given by

```
for (( i=12; i<=823; i++ ))
do
 djvused file.djvu -e 'select $i; set-page-title $((i-10)); save'
done
```

The error I get is due to the program being unable to understand $i as a number, instead of an expression. I think this is related to my small knowledge of shell scripts and djvused.

Could anyone tell me how to modify it so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote it properly with double-quotes. Using single quotes would not allow variables to be expanded and remain as literal form.

```
for (( i=12; i<=823; i++ ))
do
 djvused file.djvu -e "select $i; set-page-title $((i-10)); save"
done
```

As noted about single quotes:

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal
>   value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not
>   occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Whereas on double quotes:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters
>   ‘$’ and ‘`’ retain their special meaning within double quotes